# Django translations always rendering in english

Tags: django, translation

After looking at the trying all of the recommendations I could find on this subject, my translations still do not work whatsoever.

/settings.py file

```
# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    '/Users/samb/Projects/transtest/locale'
)

# Custom Languages
ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', ugettext('German')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
    ('fr', ugettext('French')),
    ('fr-CA', ugettext('French Canadian')),
)

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not        
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True                                                                  

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def trans(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my template file (index.html)

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
{% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>translations</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for l in LANGUAGES %}
            {{ l }}<br />
        {% endfor %}
        {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}<br />
        {% trans "Welcome to my site" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

po file (that has been compiled)
located at /Users/samb/Projects/transtest/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES

```
#: transtest/templates/index.html:13
msgid "Welcome to my site"
msgstr "Please work"
```

I can never get the 'Welcome to my site' to work. The LANGUAGES and LANGUAGE_CODE variables in my template are all working (unless I 'Accept_language: fr_CA').

After reading all the other posts on this subject and still having the same problem, I feel like I must have a silly mistake, or am missing a vital step entirely.  Any thoughts?

Update:  This is how I am testing the translation:

```
telnet localhost 8000
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /
Accept_language: fr
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Translations</title>
    </head>
    <body>

            (&#39;de&#39;, u&#39;Allemand&#39;)<br />

            (&#39;en&#39;, u&#39;Anglais&#39;)<br />

            (&#39;fr&#39;, u&#39;Fran\xe7ais&#39;)<br />

            (&#39;fr-CA&#39;, u&#39;French Canadian&#39;)<br />

        fr<br />
        Welcome to my site
    </body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I noticed that the languages are getting translated, but the 'Welcome to my site' is not.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) that LocaleMiddleware ...

> ... should come after SessionMiddleware, because LocaleMiddleware makes
>   use of session data. And it should come before CommonMiddleware
>   because CommonMiddleware needs an activated language in order to
>   resolve the requested URL.

Maybe it will help when you take account of this in your definition of the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I did overlook that but made the change to no avail.  I am starting to second guess my testing method.  All I am doing is crafting a GET request with Accept_language: fr through telnet... and seeing what spits out... perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks! I swear I read that part of the docs, and still allowed the mistake. I must have been tired!